# App Engine Python Modules and inbound mail service

Tags: google-app-engine, email, python-2.7, module, channel-api

I am using App Engine Modules in my python project. (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Background_threads)

I am also receiving email in m project:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail

I want to direct the emails to my worker module and not the default module. To that end my worker.yaml has the following settings

worker.yaml

```
    api_version: 1
    application: integrate
    module: worker
    version: 1-0-0
    runtime: python27
    threadsafe: true

    inbound_services:
    - mail

    builtins:
    - deferred: on

    handlers:

    - url: /admin/.+
      script: src.worker.main.app
      login: admin

    - url: /_ah/mail/.+
      script: src.worker.main.app
      login: admin

    - url: /.*
      script: src.worker.main.app
```

app.yaml

```
    api_version: 1
    application: integrate
    version: 1-0-0
    runtime: python27
    threadsafe: true

    builtins:
    - deferred: on

    handlers:

    - url: /admin/.+
      script: src.default.main.app
      login: admin

    - url: /.*
      script: src.default.main.app
```

I even tried adding a dispatch.yaml

```
    application: integrate

    dispatch:
    - url: "*/_ah/mail/.+"
      module: worker
```

But no matter what I do the emails which reach my app are handled by the default module. Any idea what I am missing here? I see the emails coming in but no matter what I do they only go to the default module.

Comment: Does this happen on local and on live versions?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It works locally but not live. Once live it doesn't get redirected by the dispatch.yaml.

Comment: By the way this is my exact issue. The same thing is true with the channel api. The inbound services don't seem to respect the dispatch.yaml in production.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. I haven't tried your code, but perhaps report it https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10071

Comment: you get any feedback from anyone about this?

Comment: No. I have had no feedback. I'm working around this issue with a mail handler in the default module.

Answer (score 4):

Inbound services could be used only within default module and that is expected behavior. The fact that it works for you locally in devserver is a bug, actually.

Comment: Yes this is true.This didn't use to be documented. I should added this when it was.

Answer (score -1):

Just some additional info for the answer which may help folks in a similar situation.

I noticed in the DevServer log:

"Skipping dispatch.yaml rules because /_ah/mail/[EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_APP] is not a dispatchable path."

This is no doubt due to local config, however.

Regardless, the workaround I have now using Tasks is:

- Dispatch or directly handle Inbound Mail in the default module
- Provide a script handler that creates a Task, taking the relevant MailMessage data as the payload
- Set the TaskQueue in queue.yaml to target the module you wish to process the payload data, e.g. a 'worker' module